# Installed NEST thermostat heat works fine, AC compressor comes on but no fan on AC unit

Tags: hvac, nest

I installed a new NEST thermostat last fall so only used it for heat so far.  When I went to turn on AC, compressor came on but AC unit fan didn't.  AC worked fine last year.  Could this be a NEST problem or is it an AC problem that has coincidently come up at the same time?  Thanks.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Would you tell us more about your AC (make + model, what drove it previously)? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how better to participate here.

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring at both the thermostat and air-handler/furnace ends?

Comment: Please post pictures so we can better help you. What wires were connected on your old thermostat? Where did you connect them to the Nest? If you plug your old thermostat back in, does everything function correctly?